# Reputation rank bug?

Tags: bug, reputation, rankings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Total reputation less than monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/total-reputation-less-than-monthly-reputation)

It's been a while since I noticed this odd thing: [my yearly reputation gain on electronics.stackexchange is bigger than the total](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/58/year/electronics/2012-01-01/7348#7348); the thing is that I subscribed to the Stackexchange network only this year (jan 3 SO and jan 4 EE). How is it possible?

[image]

#### UPDATE:

Reading the comments, I remember that when occurred the change in the reputation update system, I have lost something around 200 rep; may it be that it's not been registered?

Comment: Could it be that reputation was removed from your account? Like deleted answers, questions or vote-reversals?

Comment: Open the rep by time view, ensure the "show removed posts" thingy is checked(at bottom of page), copy-paste this into your URL bar `javascript:$(".expander-arrow-small-hide").click()`, hit enter. Record all the large negatives due to deletions and vote-reversals. That may account for the discrepancy--though it's still a bug.