# Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

When I went to the [Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow) to see my ranking in the reputation league, I saw this. Is this an error? My total reputation is less than my monthly reputation.
[image: total reputation less than monthly reputaion.]

Comment: Probably server cache that was not updated with deleted posts.

Comment: yep it may be, but it needs to be cleared .

Comment: Why does in need to be cleared? It's nearly a new month, and in the big scheme of things, 9 points and a monthly ranking don't make that big of a difference, does it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not crying for the pionts dear friend.Since i saw this difference gave a suggestion to the community , so that if needed it can be enhanced :)

Comment: How is this too localized? I run into this all the time. Other people keep asking me about it, too. And the difference is often like 200–600 points, not just 9. It looks like a bug, walks like a bug, and quacks like a bug.

Comment: @ЯegDwight agreed, voting to Reopen as well.

Comment: @Anna thanks for reopening, just curious how you came across this post? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It was flagged.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The discrepancy is by design:

- **Total reputation** is your current reputation on the site (accurate to within 24 hours).
- **Month reputation** is the amount by which your reputation changed that month, *excluding "private" reputation events*. Certain reputation events are excluded from your public user profile, such as deleted posts or downvotes, so those are excluded from the leagues as well.

In other words, "total reputation" includes private reputation events, while "month reputation" does not.

Comment: So you can figure out how much private rep somebody has by looking at the leagues since they joined.