# User Reputation Leagues reputation score issue

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Total reputation less than monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/total-reputation-less-than-monthly-reputation)

How does a user have a `Total Reputation` that is **less** than the `Year Reputation`?

Two Examples:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2012-01-01/373334#373334

Selkie has a `Total 730` and a `Year 749`.

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2012-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=438

Costa has a `Total 749` and a `Year 750`

Comment: Or may be a _serial voting reversal_ issue ;)

Comment: I would agree if it was a single user, but I found two examples on two pages (of 15 users). Clicking on other pages I find more.. its not a needle in a haystack issue.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2012-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=440  has 4 users with the issue with Bono with almost a 30pt discrepency.

Comment: Does bounty play into this at all?

Comment: I wonder if reputation from previous years lost in the current year (through an un-upvote, deletion, or by other means) is taken into account for the current year total. If it's not, that might explain the behaviour.

Comment: it could be a caching issue

Comment: Good Plan.. lets ignore the issue :)