# Year reputation greater than total reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Total reputation less than monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/total-reputation-less-than-monthly-reputation)

I was checking the SE [year reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2012-01-01/825789#825789), and noticed the guy right above me in the rank has an year reputation greater than his total reputation:

[image]

I could find some other similar cases on the same page:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice all those users are members for 7 months or less, so they can't have negative reputation from previous years.

So how is that possible? Is that a bug?

Comment: Dupe it is, that answers my question. Voted to close too.

Comment: I was writing the same question and you added the same before me.