# I seem to have some phantom reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

I asked this on the local meta site where it happened, but maybe someone here will have more info:

This is pretty innocuous, and I'm more asking out of curiosity, but I [seem to have](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/year/judaism) more reputation for the year than I have reputation total. Specifically at the time of this posting, 7268 total and 7288 for the year.

Month-by-month, I gained 15 reputation for the year over my total [in January](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-01-01), 3 more [in February](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-02-02), and 2 more [in March](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-02-02).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation) and [Year reputation greater than total reputation? \[duplicate\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146212/year-reputation-greater-than-total-reputation)

Comment: @animuson cetainly seems that way.