# Why I see 20 points less in reputation leagues for year / month / week?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

I joined StackOverflow a few days ago. So I am still learning about all the rules and policies. I apologize, if seems to be a silly question.

I am actually confused with one thing when I was looking at my position in reputation leagues. If you see the image, you will see that my total reputation is showing as 743, while year reputation is 723. I expect this to be the same because I joined the community a few days ago. There should be no point that can come from another year. So, why is this 20 point difference? Is there any policies on it or it's just a bug?

Note: I see 20 less in Year / Quarter / Month / Week view, but it's showing 743 in all time view.

(I am not sure is it a bug, so not tagging it as a bug).

[image: Year Reputation Image]

**UPDATE**

Today, after one day, in which I haven't gained any points by any upvote. But I have an increase in total points by 2 points. And the reason should be clear to all, I have deleted a post which had a downvote (the other way could be that the question itself is deleted). Now the score looks like the following image.

[image: Year Reputation Image Day 2]

Comment: There may be a slight lag between when these league statistics are calculated.

Comment: In that case shouldn't it be same for all time ranking too?

Comment: It's perhaps easier (less processing) to establish a "total reputation" statistic. In order to calculate a criteria-based statistic and calculate some form of rank (change) is not done very often.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/152859), the "year reputation" does not include "private" reputation events such as deleted posts. If you for example deleted 5 answers of yours, each with -2 score, it means you gained the 20 reputation back in your total reputation, however it won't be recorded in the week/month/year calculation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, in that case, I am supposed to have more points in monthly / yearly points. But I have having the opposite.

Comment: @Tareq no, because the "private event" is the deletion. In your case, it's adding to your reputation. That addition is visible in the total,  but not yearly, as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: Well, think about it from the beginning, For example I had 100 points before today. I have 5 downvotes today, so my total reputation is 90, but my yearly reputation is still 100 (since the event is private). Again I deleted my post, this is again private event, so it will take my total reputation back to 100, but it cannot anyhow make my yearly reputation down of 100. Do you get my point?

Comment: @TareqMahmood Keep in mind that the leagues only update once per day.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that it is due to the same issue as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation), though most of the time, this would cause that the monthly reputation is actually bigger.

In your case, you have either cast a downvote on answers (which costs you 1 rep, but does not count for the monthly rep since it is a private event), or you had downvoted posts that you or the community have deleted.

The latter seems likely, since you have the Peer Pressure badge.

Comment: According to the answer you referenced and the logic you provided I am supposed to have less points in my monthly / reputation, But I have having the opposite. Can you give me a link for wiki or documentation where the policies on this matter is clearly explained?

Comment: @TareqMahmood In the screenshot you gave, you have 723 yearly reputation (equals the monthly reputation) and your total reputation is 743. So you have less points in your monthly reputation. But actually it is more common to have it vice versa.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't think of the possible scenario which can give me this opposite situation.

Comment: @TareqMahmood, If an answer of yours with positive score is deleted. This happens sometimes when you write an answer to a question that deserves to be deleted, even though your answer is good.