# How does a reputation event become a "private" reputation event?

Tags: support, reputation, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

The answer to [Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141628/349643) mentions private reputation.

> - **Month reputation** is the amount by which your reputation changed that month, *excluding "private" reputation events*. Certain reputation events are excluded from your public user profile, such as deleted posts or downvotes, so those are excluded from the leagues as well.

Can someone please explain this in more detail and maybe give examples of how a deleted post or down vote becomes a "private" reputation event?

Comment: They don't *become* private, they just *are* private. They impact your rep but aren't shown to users other than you. Use an incognito window to look at your profile to see what's public.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have found out I duplicated a previous question. See the answer to the dupe to find that some events **do** become private